# background-repeat stops when zooming

Tags: css, background, repeat

I've set the background of my footer to `background-repeat: repeat-x` but for some reason when I zoom in, the background stops repeating... The blue bar you see should be repeating the whole width of the window according to the CSS rules (and he does, execpt when I start zooming in)

Is this normal? If yes, how can I prevent or pass by this. If not, what could be the cause?

[image]

**EDIT:**
I just figured out if you set the width of the body to e.g. 1,000px or 5,000px the footer starts expanding, but when I zoom out to the normal size, the site is extremely large... And `width: 100%` didn't work out either.

Comment: Try " *background-attachment:fixed;* ", but I'm not sure before see the CSS style, so I can't answer in the answer box.

Comment: @sysop, Thanks for the hint, but the fixed statement isn't working... Let me know what you need to answer the question

Comment: can you post the code? have you validated your html/css?

Comment: Can you share the URL of the above page or may be a demo on http://jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

Give the footer a width of 100% and then give it a min-width equal to the width of your content. So if your content has a fixed width of 960px for example, your css would be:

```
#content { width: 960px; }
#footer { width: 100%; min-width: 960px; }
```